# Finding the dual of a problem $\min_{w,b} \sum_{j=1}^{n}{\max(0,w_j)}$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, duality-theorems

Consider the optimization problem for support vector machine with

$(x_i,y_i),i=1,2,\ldots,m$ is the training data set

$y_i=\{-1,1\}$

$w\in \mathbb R^n$

$\min_{w,b} \sum_{j=1}^{n}{\max(0,w_j)}\\\text{s.t.: } y_i(w^Tx_i+b)\geq1,\forall i.$

Derive the dual of this problem.

Hello I am trying to learn optimization techniques and am new to the concept of dual.

I understand that I am supposed to minimize the Lagrangian with respect to $w$ and $b$ in this case

$L=\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\max(0,w_j)}-\sum_{i=1}^{F}{\lambda_i[(w^Tx_i+b)-1]},$

but I am unsure how to proceed in carrying out the proper differentiation.

If someone can demonstrate deriving the dual of this problem.

Comment: Boyd and Vandenberghe has a good discussion of support vector machines.

Comment: You could start by eliminating the $\max$ before using duality. Let $m_j := \max(0, w_j)$. Then you can write your objective as the sum of $m_j$ and introduce the constraints $0 \le m_j$ and $w_j \le m_j$.